# Why ORM doen't send me back the Object?

Tags: php, laravel-5, orm

I am working on Laravel 5.4 and i have a question about ORM.
Why the behaviour of this two samples of codes send differents informations :

```
Foo::whereId(13632)->first(); => null

DB::table('foo')->where('id', '=', 13632)->first(); => Foo{...}
```

My class Foo :

```
class Foo extends Model
{
       protected $table = 'foo';

 ...
}
```

If i try do to this in my db (SQL) :

```
SELECT * FROM `foo` WHERE `id` = 13632
```

I got the line with all the datas.

And if i try to do the same another id, it works :

```
Foo::whereId(13634)->first();  => Foo{...}

DB::table('foo')->where('id', '=', 13634)->first(); => Foo{...}
```

And if I try to do in Phpmyadmin :

```
SELECT * FROM `foo` WHERE `id` = 13634
```

I get all the right datas.

Thank you.

Comment: What you want with above both query code ? both should return single object where id = 13632

Comment: Table `foo` and `doctors` are actually two different things. What does `Foo::find(13632)` return?

Comment: @NikleshRaut : Yes that's why i expect but the fact is that Foo::whereId(13632)->first(); return null and not the Object Foo.

Comment: @kerbholz: It's a mistake, the table is "foo" and not "doctors". I correct my post. thank you

Comment: what you get  from  `Foo::find(13632);` ? Also please ensure that you have include this Foo class as `use App\Foo` ?

Comment: @NikleshRaut  Foo::find(13632); return null. i have check, Foo is include in my file (\App\Foo)

Comment: I think you don't included Foo proper, please try as `App\Foo` instead `\App\Foo`

Comment: And what from `Foo::where('id',13632)->first();` ?

Comment: @NikleshRaut : I got the right include (App\Foo) and the other function of my class work fine.

Comment: @NikleshRaut : Doctor::where('id',13632)->first(); return null. As Doctor::where('id','=', 13632)->first();

Comment: Why not you share your original code  ? there's only your problem is hidden ?

Comment: @NikleshRaut, My class (Foo which is Doctor irl) made 900 lines and my controller more than 500. I just wanna as clear as possible. That's why i didn't post all the code. And i made my test in single function in my Controller.